# "Place Order" button on checkout page not working - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, onestepcheckout, place-order

When I click on "Order Now" on the checkout page nothing happens. This is both for the Third party One Step Checkout and the generic Magento One Step Checkout.

Not sure what could be causing this.

Please could you kindly advise.

Thanks.

Comment: I have this problem too. Was this resolved? If so, how?

Comment: @Dacod did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

At first look at browser console output (also for network - check request's responses).
Check log files (there were no errors probably but who knows).
You can also debug with xdebug. Its awesome tool for check whats going on in project.

There may be some error on order's validation.

Answer (score -1):

I am experiencing something like your problem with a 3rd party extension and I have been told that I should reset the permissions on the server where the installation is, or let the hosting company do it...this is because extensions have to be able to write (and execute?)...I hope this could be of any help!